# Django manage.py commands with Google App Engine and Vagrant

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google App Engine app and I'm running Windows with Vagrant. I have an Ubuntu installation which I access via vagrant ssh. On that machine I installed the Google App Engine SDK for Python and I can successfully deploy my app with:

```
appcfg.py update myapp --oauth2 --noauth_local_webserver
```

The `--noauth_local_parameter` allows me to copy the oauth URL and paste in the browser on my Windows machine, because on the Linux machine I have no GUI. Everything is working fine.

But now I want to use the Django `manage.py syncdb` command, to create the tables in Google Cloud SQL. The problem is, when I execute that command, the text-based w3n browser starts for the authorization, and then I get the error message that the browser does not support javascript.

I'd like to run the `manage.py` commands with the --noauth_local_webserver flag, but that is not supported by the `manage.py` commands. How can I solve this? I have already installed an Ubuntu virtual machine with GUI and given the app the permission and manage.py works fine on that machine, but when I try to execute the command on the Vagrant (non GUI) machine, it stills want to open the browser for permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I manually copied the oauth `.dat` file to the vagrant server, and `manage.py syncdb` is now working, but the website still can't connect in the browser; it says:

`No valid OAuth 2.0 credentials.  Before using the Google SQL Service backend on dev_appserver, you must first run "manage.py syncdb" and proceed through the given instructions to fetch an OAuth 2.0 token.`

It seems to be the same errors as [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9006). In my case it seemed that the necessary `GOOGLE_SQL_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN` environment variable was not set. I copied this refresh token from the `.dat` file and set it in the app.yaml:

```
env_variables:
  GOOGLE_SQL_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN: "..."
```

Now everything is working fine.